# Mathematical generalization of the equilibrium point

Tags: optimization

Let $U$ be an open set $U \subset  \mathbb R^n$.  Let $f$ be a class-2 function $f: U → \mathbb R$.

Prove or disprove the following statement. 
$∇^2 f=0$ and $∇f= 0$ at $x_0 \in U$ implies $x_0$ is the saddle point.

Comment: @JavaMan/ Yes. That notation means what you said. =ㅅ=;;

Comment: This is false. Take, for example, $f(x) = x^4$ in one dimension.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan/ Thank you. @_@ Can you give the another example in R^2 ?

Comment: $f(x, y) = x^4 + y^4$. I could give you a $3$-dimensional example too...

Comment: More general examples show that no condition on finitely many derivatives of $f$ suffices to determine exactly when a point is a saddle point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notation $\nabla^2 f$ is ambiguous: it can mean the Hessian matrix or its trace (the Laplacian). I will write $\Delta f$ for the Laplacian and $D^2f$ for the Hessian matrix. Here is something to fill the answer box:

> If $\nabla f(x_0)=0$, $\Delta f(x_0)=0$, but $D^2f(x_0)$ is not the zero matrix, then $x_0$ is a saddle point.

Proof: Since $D^2f(x_0)$ is symmetric, it is diagonalizable and not all of the eigenvalues are zero. The sum of eigenvalues is $0$. Therefore, $D^2f(x_0)$ has at least one positive eigenvalue and at least one negative eigenvalue.